# How can I teach High School kids that rest is important in progression and resistance training (supercompensation)?

Tags: rest, compensation

How do you explain to your athletes/players that rest is important in simpler English? Some of my guys go 7 days/week playing basketball and I need a compelling argument to tell them to take a day off once in a while.

Comment: Consider sports.stackexchange too.

Comment: It depends on the type of training - there's no reason why you can't do skills training 7 days a week. But fot strength/aerobic training consider this argument - it's not the training that makes you improve, it's your body's _recovery_ and supercompensation that makes you improve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Maybe not?

I'm not sure that high school athletes *need* to take a day off of playing basketball. Their recovery is probably amazing, and a game of ball isn't necessarily very taxing.

A day off is definitely necessary if they're getting sluggish or feeling beat up, or if they're actually training — meaning sprints, distance running, lifting weights, or drilling hard. But if they're only doing light drills and scrimmaging, I don't see a reason to mandate a day off unless they specifically need it. Young athletes are very durable.

#### Deontological policy

Then again, maybe they really should rest. I wouldn't try arguing the point. Just make a soft rule for them. Tell them that even the very best usually reserve Sunday as a day of rest. They can go for a walk and shoot hoops, but no organized games. If they break the rule, they experience the consequences, and will learn from it.